# Is my minified javascript conflicting with my AWeber javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cdn, minify, cloudflare

I’ve got a page with an AWeber popup form that’s intended to be made visible by clicking a “Get Music” button. You can see it here:

http://www.radionowhere.net

This was working fine until I set up Cloudflare as a CDN for my site and started using it to minify my CSS and JS. Now the Aweber form appears as soon as my page loads, without waiting for the button to be clicked.

Checking the page source, it seems as though the AW javascript in the middle of the page hasn’t been affected by the minification, so I assume the problem must have something to do with conflicting script that Cloudflare has been minified.

Anyone with an idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Seeing as how there are no responses, and I haven't figured it out yet, I'm changing my page so that this popup is no longer required. If anyone wants to answer, I'd still be interested, but I'm working around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have Rocket Loader turned on as well? I'm inclined to say it is less likely of an issue with Minify than Rocket Loader.

Comment: I did. Now I've got Rocket Loader turned off, but have ticked Minify Javascript back on. And it seems to be working - thx!